# "Total Fees" is blank on Event Registration Page

Tags: civievent

Why is "Total Fees" blank on my event registration page? I checked for errors using firebug but there are no errors. The total does show on the confirmation page. I'm using Joomla version 3.6.5. and civicrm version 4.7.14
[image]

Comment: You should update your question with the version of CiviCRM you are using, and the CMS you are integrating it with

Comment: @jackrabbithanna is right - there was a similar bug fixed in up-to-date versions.  Also, please indicate whether or not this is configured as a price set or not - that sometimes affects what's displayed.

Comment: I added my CMS and version to my post. Should I update civicrm to 4.7.15?